# Products for probability theory using zero sets instead of open sets

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

(For all of this post, at least [Countable Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) is assumed to hold.)

For all [Tychonoff spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space) $\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle$ :

Define $\mathbf{Z}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle)$ to be the set of subsets $S$ of $X$ such that there exists a

continuous $\: f : X\to (-\infty,\scriptsize+\normalsize\infty) \:$ such that $\;\;\; \{x\in X : f(x)=0\} \; = \; S \;\;\;$.

Define $\; \operatorname{Ba}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle) \;$ to be the sigma-algebra on $X$ generated by $\mathbf{Z}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle)$.

Define $\operatorname{UM}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle)$ to be the set of subsets $S_0$ of $X$ such that

for all probability measures $\: \mu : \operatorname{Ba}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle) \to (-\infty,\scriptsize+\normalsize\infty) \:$,

there exists a member $S_1$ of $\operatorname{Ba}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle)$ such that the symmetric difference between $S_0$ and $S_1$ is $\mu$-[null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set#Definition).

It follows that $\operatorname{UM}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.06 in}\rangle)$ is a sigma-algebra on $X$.

Let $\langle X,\mathcal{T}_0\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\mathcal{T}_1\rangle$ be Tychonoff spaces. $\;\;$ Let $\: \mu_0 : \operatorname{UM}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}_0\rangle) \to (-\infty,\scriptsize+\normalsize\infty) \:$

and $\: \mu_1 : \operatorname{UM}(\langle Y,\mathcal{T}_1\rangle) \to (-\infty,\scriptsize+\normalsize\infty) \:$ be probability measures. $\;\;$ Let $\mathcal{T}_2$ be the product topology

on $\: X\times Y \:$. $\;\;$ It follows that $\langle X\times Y,\mathcal{T}_2\rangle$ is a Tychonoff space and for all members $S_0$ of

$\operatorname{UM}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}_0\rangle)$, for all members $S_1$ of $\operatorname{UM}(\langle Y,\mathcal{T}_1\rangle)$, $\;\; S_0 \times S_1 \: \in \: \operatorname{UM}(\langle X\times Y,\mathcal{T}_2\rangle) \;\;$.

If there is a [measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Measurable) [Aleph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number), then there is an example where (*), defined as

> there exists a unique probability measure $\: \mu_2 : \operatorname{UM}(\langle X\times Y,\mathcal{T}_2\rangle) \to (-\infty,\scriptsize+\normalsize\infty) \:$ such that
>   
>   for all members $S_0$ of $\operatorname{UM}(\langle X,\mathcal{T}_0\rangle)$, for all members $S_1$ of $\operatorname{UM}(\langle Y,\mathcal{T}_1\rangle)$,
>   
>   $\mu_2(S_0 \times S_1) \; = \; \mu_0(S_0) \cdot \mu_1(S_1)$

does not hold.

> ${}$1. $\:$ Does there provably-in-ZFC exist an example where (*) does not hold?
>   
>
>   1a. $\:$ If yes, how much of AC (beyond Countable Choice) does such a proof need to use?
>   
>
>
>   ${}$2.
>   
>
>   What amount of Choice (beyond Countable Choice) and/or
>   
>
>   conditions on $\langle X,\mathcal{T}_0\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\mathcal{T}_1\rangle$ are known to force (*) to hold?

I don't know any way full AC makes this easier, and the only condition I already know for 2 is:

$\langle X,\mathcal{T}_0\rangle$ and $\langle Y,\mathcal{T}_1\rangle$ both have [countable networks](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/spaces-with-countable-network/) $\;\; \implies \;\;$ (*)

Comment: $\operatorname{Ba}$ stands for Baire (Dudley's definition, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_set#More_general_definitions) $\;$

Comment: (*) says "there exists a unique" ... when if fails, do you expect existence or uniqueness to fail?


Comment: Your "measurable cardinal" failure even happens if you use the discrete topology in the two factors, right?


Comment: I expect uniqueness to fail. $\;$ Yes, and for that matter it happens even for a finite-(real-)valued measurable Aleph, since any such measure could be rescaled to be a probability measure. 